# Kubernetes: How do I tell what GCP service account my service is running as?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts

I'm getting a

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/adstudio-sandbox1/instances/us-central1~adspromosdb-sandbox/connectSettings
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request.",
      "reason": "notAuthorized"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The client is not authorized to make this request."
}
```

I guessed a service account based on the name of my service and gave it the Cloud SQL Admin/Editor/Client and Storage Object Admin roles but I'm still getting the same error. I'm wondering if it's not using the service account that I think it is.

How can I confirm what service account my service is running as? (And how does it relate to Kubernetes? Does a cluster or a namespace always share 1 service account?)

Answer (score 1):

A Google Cloud Service Account and a Kubernetes Service Account are two different things.

For connecting to a Cloud SQL database from a Kubernetes cluster, it is recommended and easiest to use an [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-auth-proxy) to "assist" with the authentication from the cluster to the database. It is also possible to use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy as a local CLI tool, to connect to your Cloud SQL database in a secure way.

See [Connect to Cloud SQL from Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-kubernetes) for a full guide on how to setup connection from Kubernetes to a Cloud SQL database.